# Will disabling LTE extend my battery life even if I'm not using it?

Tags: battery, battery-life, mobile-network, mobile-data, 4g

I was just wondering, if disabling LTE will improve my battery life even if I'm never using it (there's no LTE in my country).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might marginally increase your battery life, since if the network selection is set to Auto, it will periodically poll the networks to see if LTE is available. Since it won't find it anyway, why not disable it and restrict it to your available networks?

Comment: Thank you, I thought it but wanted to make sure.